# Unable to ping when two interfaces (ethernet and wifi) are active

Tags: network-programming

I have a linux system with two interfaces active:

1. Bridge `br0`: containing two wifi interfaces (2.4 and 5GHz). The 5GHz interface is connected to a network. The bridge interface br0 is able to obtain an IP from that network (192.168.1.107). This network provides internet without any restrictions.
2. Ethernet `eth0`: Connected to a different network (than the 5GHz network) and also has an IP address from it (10.102.xx.xx). This network provides internet behind a proxy.

With this arrangement, I am not able to ping any website, e.g. `ping google.com` fails. If I remove ethernet momentarily, the ping succeeds. Ping also succeeds if I specify the interface to ping from. e.g. `ping -I br0 google.com` succeeds.

An HTML5 application running on the system needs to load a URL, which is failing due to the above mentioned problem.

Could you please help me understand why the ping/wget/curl fails when two interfaces are active and how I can fix this?

The routing table looks like this:

```
# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.102.132.1    0.0.0.0         UG    202    0        0 eth0
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    208    0        0 br0
10.102.132.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.128 U     202    0        0 eth0
127.0.0.0       0.0.0.0         255.0.0.0       U     0      0        0 lo
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     208    0        0 br0
```

Comment: Can you provide the result of running the following command to display your route table: `ip route` or `route -n` (take into account that those programs might bin on /sbin or /usr/sbin and not in your path unless your user is root)

Comment: Hi Elyavarado, here's the output: # route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.102.132.1    0.0.0.0         UG    202    0        0 eth0
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    208    0        0 br0
10.102.132.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.128 U     202    0        0 eth0
127.0.0.0       0.0.0.0         255.0.0.0       U     0      0        0 lo
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     208    0        0 br0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your route table it shows that you have 2 default gateways when you have both interfaces connected, even though the lowest metric should give preference to the 10.102.132.1 gateway, that might not be what you want given that it is behind a proxy.

If you run the following command you should be able to remove the default gateway on the eth0, and will be able to ping again:

`sudo route del -net 0.0.0.0 gw 10.102.132.1 netmask 0.0.0.0 dev eth0`

This command is not persistent, so when you disconnect and reconnect that interface the route will be reset.

Comment: Thanks for your input, Elyalvarado. I googled a bit and added another entry to the routing table for br0 and changed the metric to 200. That solved the issue for now. However, the original issue that I did not mention earlier is that the html5 application may choose one of two URLs: one is accessible on 10.102.xx.xx network and the other is reachable over internet (192.168.xx.xx). I need to figure out how to allow the application to access either URL without worrying about the routing table. :-)

Comment: If you're accessing your app through an IP address it'll take the closest route to that address. If not you'll have to find what IP address your DNS is resolving, and then you'll now what route its taking. If you want to always resolve the 'internet' IP address you might be able to change your DNS configuration to use 8.8.8.8 or 1.1.1.1 as DNS servers (which also has other adventages)

Comment: For now, I can add a route for a specific subnet or IP as one of the URLs uses a specific IP address. Alternatively, I can monitor for change in a system variable that changes based on user selection (long story) and add or remove a route accordingly. Thanks for your help! :-)

Comment: The question is not on-topic for Stack Overflow as defined in the [help]. Please don't answer such questions; instead, you should flag them for attention and they will be closed or migrated appropriately.